# How to join multiple "select" statements

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, join

I have three tables :

1.Actions:

```
ActionCode IsBuy Is Sell 
1            1       0
2            1       0
3            0       1
4            1       0
5            1       0
6            0       1
```

2.ShareType :

```
Share IsStock IsBond IsOption  
    1       1        0       0
    2       1        0       0 
    3       0        1       0 
    4       1        0       0
    5       1        0       0 
    6       0        1       0
```

No overlapping in both of the tables. Meaning, Option cannot be a stock, buy cannot be a sell etc.

and a table like this - Transaction which I've created using table 1 and table 2 (see above)

```
Date AccUser Amount IsBuy IsSell IsStock IsBond IsOption 
1.1.14  132   400     1      0      0      1      0
1.1.14  132   200     1      0      0      1      0
1.1.14  132   500     1      0      0      0      1
2.1.14  133   250     0      1      1      0      1
```

Now, I need to perform a set of descriptive statistics calculations for each combination of action and sharetype :

```
Select Date, AccUser, count(AccUser) Over (Partition by AccUser, Date) as Cnt1
, sum(Amount) over (partition by AccUser,Date) as Amnt1
from transaction 
where IsBuy = 1 and IsBond = 1 

Select Date, AccUser, count(AccUser) Over (Partition by AccUser, Date) as Cnt2
, sum(Amount) over (partition by AccUser,Date) as Amnt2
from transaction 
where IsBuy = 1 and IsStock = 1 

Select Date, AccUser, count(AccUser) Over (Partition by AccUser, Date) as Cnt3
, sum(Amount) over (partition by AccUser,Date) as Amnt3
from transaction 
where IsBuy = 1 and IsOption = 1 


Select Date, AccUser, count(AccUser) Over (Partition by AccUser, Date) as Cnt4
, sum(Amount) over (partition by AccUser,Date) as Amnt4
from transaction 
where IsSell = 1 and IsBond = 1 

Select Date, AccUser, count(AccUser) Over (Partition by AccUser, Date) as Cnt5
, sum(Amount) over (partition by AccUser,Date) as Amnt5
from transaction 
where IsSell = 1 and IsStock = 1 

Select Date, AccUser, count(AccUser) Over (Partition by AccUser, Date) as Cnt6
, sum(Amount) over (partition by AccUser,Date) as Amnt6
from transaction 
where IsSell = 6 and IsOption = 6
```

I've written here only a sample of share types and a sample  of actions. 
Anyway, I now have many "select" (see above) and I need to join all of this to create this table:

```
Date AccUser cnt1 amnt1 cnt2 amnt2 cnt3 amnt3 cnt4 amnt4 cnt5 amnt5 cnt6 amnt6
1.1.14 132     2   600    0    0     1    500  0    0      0     0    0    0  
2.1.14 133     0    0     0    0     0     0   0    0      1    250   0    0
```

Any elgant way to join all of this "select"? thank's!

Comment: Yep, stick UNION ALL between each statement.

Comment: Please don't tell me you named a SQL Server table `transaction` - avoid naming things with reserved/keywords for your own sanity!

Comment: thank's but don't worry :)

Answer (score 0):

join is not working here simple use union all of them as

```
Select Date, AccUser, count(AccUser) Over (Partition by AccUser, Date) as Cnt1
, sum(Amount) over (partition by AccUser,Date) as Amnt1
from transaction 
where IsBuy = 1 and IsBond = 1 
UNION ALL
Select Date, AccUser, count(AccUser) Over (Partition by AccUser, Date) as Cnt2
, sum(Amount) over (partition by AccUser,Date) as Amnt2
from transaction 
where IsBuy = 1 and IsStock = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UNION ALL

```
Select Date, AccUser, count(AccUser) Over (Partition by AccUser, Date) as Cnt1
, sum(Amount) over (partition by AccUser,Date) as Amnt1
from transaction 
where IsBuy = 1 and IsBond = 1 
UNION ALL
Select Date, AccUser, count(AccUser) Over (Partition by AccUser, Date) as Cnt2
, sum(Amount) over (partition by AccUser,Date) as Amnt2
from transaction 
where IsBuy = 1 and IsStock = 1 
UNION ALL
Select Date, AccUser, count(AccUser) Over (Partition by AccUser, Date) as Cnt3
, sum(Amount) over (partition by AccUser,Date) as Amnt3
from transaction 
where IsBuy = 1 and IsOption = 1 

UNION ALL
Select Date, AccUser, count(AccUser) Over (Partition by AccUser, Date) as Cnt4
, sum(Amount) over (partition by AccUser,Date) as Amnt4
from transaction 
where IsSell = 1 and IsBond = 1 
UNION ALL
Select Date, AccUser, count(AccUser) Over (Partition by AccUser, Date) as Cnt5
, sum(Amount) over (partition by AccUser,Date) as Amnt5
from transaction 
where IsSell = 1 and IsStock = 1 
UNION ALL
Select Date, AccUser, count(AccUser) Over (Partition by AccUser, Date) as Cnt6
, sum(Amount) over (partition by AccUser,Date) as Amnt6
from transaction 
where IsSell = 6 and IsOption = 6
```